# Site URL CodeIgniter Not Working

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have Controller on CI like this

```
class Testing extends CI_Controller {

//put your code here

public function xx() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('testing');
}

public function linkURL() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['test'] = "testing123";
    $this->load->view('xxx_view', $data);
}

}
```

I'm running on function linkURL and call view xxx_view, the code on view like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $segment = array('Testing', 'xx');
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url($segment); ?>">Link</a>
</body>
```

view call a href and using helper site_url to call Controller Testing and function xx. But the link is not working. I am already capture on firebug and link looks like weird. The Link on href contain `*http://::1*`. How to solved that link

[image]

Comment: When your link starts with `http://::1` Make sure you have your base url  config set `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/'`

Comment: And I would autoload the url helper so your not doubling up on code.

Answer (score 1):

You can `print_r($_SERVER)` in your controller and check it. or You can use

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8081/your-project/'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, seem to you sent data `test` to `view xxx_view` but not using this variable. try `echo $test` and I see in url using `xxx` not `xx`

Answer (score 0):

You need to autoload URL helper in your config/autoload.php.This time you are loading URl helper in function. That will not work for your view.

Comment: Same time you also need to check your base URL in config.php